# Adobe Acrobat Pro: Error 110 "The document could not be saved."

Tags: windows-7, pdf, adobe-acrobat

I opened a PDF, highlighted some text, tried to save it, and got the following error message, which preventing me from saving the amended PFD:

> The document could not be saved. There was a problem reading this document (110)

[image]

How to fix it?

I use Adobe Acrobat XI Pro with Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate.

Comment: Try to save the document without comments under a different name, and then try to comment on that copy. If you get the same effect, deactivate the "Save as optimizes for fast web view" option in the Preferences.

Comment: @MaxWyss Thanks, the issue is that I want to keep the comments. Luckily I haven't encountered the issue since then.

Comment: One possibility to retrieve the comments from an earlier save would be to export them and import the resulting FDF into a virgin version of the document.

Comment: Was this solved? How did you get rid of the problem?

Comment: @Solace unsolved

Comment: I switched to Nitro PDF reader. It's working fine.

Comment: Adobo0's answer [on this page](https://forums.adobe.com/people/Adobo0) seems to have helped many.

Answer (score 7):

How to fix the PDF:

1. Install [Foxit Reader](https://www.foxitsoftware.com/pdf-reader/) (free)
2. Open the PDF with Foxit Reader
3. highlight anything
4. save and close

The PDF can now be opened normally by Adobe Reader.

Comment: I can attest that this method works, thank you.  Apparently, Foxit fixes the document as it is saving.

Answer (score 0):

I had the problem on Mac where the PDF file itself was at fault (the only one that I cannot save with Adobe Reader DC). So I opened it with Preview and exported it as a new PDF. I lost all my previous bookmarks and comments, but at least it can then be saved and edited normally.

Answer (score 0):

I could solve this problem by downloading d[FoxitReader](https://www.foxitsoftware.com/pdf-reader/) which is free pdf reader software then open my PDF files through it then save my file again immediately. after doing these steps you can open your PDF files without seeing the error.

Answer (score -1):

I use PDF24 Creator as my PDF printer.
This successfully fixed a PDF with a 110 error by opening in PDF24 and saving as a new PDF.